# How to use SLD Select control?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms

I have a WMS layer and i want to get fid of polygon in it by click it. How can i do it?
I know that i can create WFS layer from this WMS and get feature attributes from layer or store. But its possible do this use just WMS? I dont want use WFS Layer couse it may contain ~30k features. But if i will use WFS Layer with visible=false selection control will be works?
I find SLDSelect control its can help me?
Maybe its possible to do like in gxp library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMS has standard (but optional) request [GetFeatureInfo](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcims/9.3/General/mergedProjects/wms_connect/wms_connector/get_featureinfo.htm) which should be implemented by most WMS servers. You do not need WFS for just object identification.

Comment: I use GetFeatureInfo early but i have only several test objects on layer. How i remember get ifo about all features from layer or its possible to get info of only one feature?

Comment: GetFeatureInfo allows you to get attributes - in your case, the fid - of one feature, the one the user clicks on.